# Accessing text field inside html table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to access text placed inside rows of a dynamic table in javascript.

My table structure:-

```
<BODY>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="650px" border="2">
    <TR >
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]" /></TD>
        <TD ><INPUT type="text" name="txt[]" /></TD>
        <TD>
            <INPUT type="text" name="time[]" />                         
        </TD>

    </TR>
</TABLE>
</BR>
</BR>
<INPUT type = "button" value = "Submit" onclick = "myFunction()"></BODY>
```

--
Thanks

Comment: Access is using what? `javascript` or some server-side language after posting? Your question is lacking very important information. When do you want to *"access text placed inside rows of a dynamic table"*? During `input`? After `change`? At the point of `submit`ting?

Comment: - Access using javascript, I want to get the information from table after submitting

Comment: Use the `.value` property of the element.

Comment: @sakshi Unless you use AJAX, submitting the form reloads the page, so you can't do anything after submitting. Do you mean before the form is submitted

Comment: @Barmar I am making a dynamic table where user can add any number of rows and fill the appropriate entries in the rows, as soon as user hits the submit I want to access all the information and use them for my further processing. So I mean after the table is submitted. I don't require values inside table before it is submitted.

Comment: If anyone could answer this question as well then it would be great help, thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668507/handling-multiple-timers-using-cookies-in-javascript-for-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean to get the whole input value in the table, you can do this.

```
var a = document.getElementById("dataTable").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

so `var a` became an array and inside it are elements that you wanted to get the value just use loop.

```
var e = a.length; // get how many input inside the table
for(x=0;x<e;x++){
    console.log(a[x].name+" the value inside is  "+a[x].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have id for specified row? If you dont have place id on row from where you want to change text and "catch" it with javascript. function is called var a= document.getElementById('ID_OF_SAMPLE_ROW').value and text is stored into variable a. This function must be called on click or something similar so you must specify when you read and from which row.

Answer (score 0):

Simply grab the elements in question with **[`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)**, and then return their `.value`. You can see whether the checkbox is checked or not with `.checked`.

Note that `.getElementsByName()` returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of objects, so you'll want to grab the first result with `[0]`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let chk = document.getElementsByName('chk[]')[0].checked;
  let txt = document.getElementsByName('txt[]')[0].value;
  let time = document.getElementsByName('time[]')[0].value;
  
  console.log("Checkbox checked?:", chk);
  console.log("Text:", txt);
  console.log("Time:", time);
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
  <TABLE id="dataTable" width="650px" border="2">
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]" />
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" name="txt[]" />
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT type="text" name="time[]" />
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  <BR />
  <BR />
  <INPUT type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
</BODY>
```

Note that your final `<input>` is missing the closing `/`, and your `</br>` tags should be `<br />`. These have been fixed in the above example.

Comment: `<input>` doesn't need a closing `/`. This is HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: @Obsidian Age Can you please help me with this question as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668507/handling-multiple-timers-using-cookies-in-javascript-for-chrome-extension